# SQL Server Agent is not running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm unable to start the SQL Server agent in services. I'm getting the following error while starting.

> SQL Server Agent service in local computer started and then stopped. Some services automatically stop if  they have no work to do, for example, the performance logs and alert service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has its own log - check that as well as the Windows event log. Also, see if the account that SQL Server Agent runs under has the correct password etc. Will the Agent run under the Local System account (temporarily)?

Answer (score 0):

That is generic message for any problem with launch of services.
You could try to find error's description in logs (i am not sure - windows error log or specific log file).
Try repair reinstalling SQL Server or Service Packs.

Comment: I changed the account from Local System to NT Authority\Network Service. Now it is working. But, don't know why it is not running with local service...

Answer (score 0):

Check out your SQL agent log which should be here, replacing the bracketed pieces with whatever is appropriate... although this is just the default install directory, so it may be slightly different if you installed somewhere else:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.\MSSQL\Log\SQLAGENT.OUT

Try changing the service back to Local System and start it then post the most recent ouput in that file, might be able to help more with that.